# Problems with sql table alias

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

```
SELECT last_name
FROM   employees,
       (SELECT last_name AS man_ln
        FROM   employees
               JOIN (SELECT last_name              AS emp_ln,
                            employee_id,
                            Employees.manager_id   AS emp_man_id,
                            Departments.manager_id AS dep_man_id
                     FROM   employees
                            FULL OUTER JOIN Departments USING (department_id)
                     WHERE  Employees.manager_id <> Departments.manager_id) tableA
                 ON employees.employee_id = tableA.emp_man_id) tableB
WHERE  employees.employee_id = tableA.dep_man_id
```

I try his query, but I receive:

> ORA-00904: "TABLEA"."DEP_MAN_ID": invalid identifier

Can I have access to TableA?

p.s  `tableA.emp_man_id` works correctly.

Comment: You want to refer to `tableB.dep_man_id`.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/5OzNSbW) this is the common schema.

And this is my task: (Up is a part of resolving)

Display the employees (employees), whose manager (manager_id) does not coincide with the manager of the department,
where the staff member (department_id, see. manager_id also attribute table departments).
Need to bring 3 columns, each of which - the name (last_name): employee employee's manager, department manager.
Note: use explicit naming of the result set columns (aliases).

Comment: The issue is properly scoping your identifiers as @Andrew Shepherd notes below.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Alias for `SELECT last_name AS man_ln FROM employees` so I made `employees` as its alias. Try this query:

```
SELECT last_name
FROM   employees,
       ((SELECT last_name AS man_ln
        FROM   employees) AS employees
        JOIN (SELECT last_name              AS emp_ln,
                     employee_id,
                     Employees.manager_id   AS emp_man_id,
                     Departments.manager_id AS dep_man_id
              FROM   employees
                     FULL OUTER JOIN Departments USING (department_id)
              WHERE  Employees.manager_id <> Departments.manager_id) tableA
          ON employees.employee_id = tableA.emp_man_id) tableB
WHERE  employees.employee_id = tableB.dep_man_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

In your inner subquery, do

```
SELECT last_name as man_ln, tableA.dep_manId
```

and in your outer query, replace the WHERE clause with

```
WHERE employees.employee_id = tableB.dep_man_id
```

And this will work.

This is all about scoping the names.

- the main query has the tables `employees`, `tableB`
- `tableB` is created from a *subquery* consisting of `employees`, `tableA`

The tables that make up the subquery are not visible outside of the scope of the subquery.

Below is the same query with indentation that clearly indicates the levels of subqueries.

```
SELECT 
    last_name 
FROM 
    employees,         
    (
        SELECT 
            last_name AS man_ln,
            tableA.dep_man_id    -- << You need this to make it visible to the outer query 
        FROM 
            employees 
        JOIN
            (SELECT 
                last_name AS emp_ln, 
                employee_id, 
                Employees.manager_id AS emp_man_id, 
                Departments.manager_id AS dep_man_id  
             FROM 
                employees 
             FULL OUTER JOIN 
                Departments 
             USING (department_id) 
             WHERE Employees.manager_id <> Departments.manager_id
          ) tableA
          ON employees.employee_id = tableA.emp_man_id 
     ) tableB  
WHERE employees.employee_id = tableB.dep_man_id
```

Comment: I put this query and had ORA-00904: "TABLEA"."DEP_MAN_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: @OlegBaranenko OK, I don't know why you would be getting that. My suggestion is to copy-and-paste the internal queries and seeing if they work one their own. Good luck.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm), it may be important to run [catproc.sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SRF73/ch6.htm) with this error. Try Andrew's solution above with this in mind. Also checking the trace file can give you more detail on particular error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle expert but check the `FULL OUTER JOIN...USING()` clause. Try adjusting the `USING (department_id)` to `ON Departments.department_id = Employees.department_id` OR specify a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, or simply `JOIN` with `USING` clause.

If I am correct, FULL OUTER JOINs cannot run with the [USING](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqljusing.html) clause. Hence, your Departments table may not be effectively joined into the TableA result set, causing the `dep_man_id` reference to be an invalid identifier.

Comment: This part of qeury work without error:
(SELECT last_name              AS emp_ln,
                            employee_id,
                            Employees.manager_id   AS emp_man_id,
                            Departments.manager_id AS dep_man_id
                     FROM   employees
                            FULL OUTER JOIN Departments USING (department_id)
                     WHERE  Employees.manager_id <> Departments.manager_id) tableA